# Strange page file settings behaviour?

Tags: pagefile

We have a Citrix server that struggles with space mainly due to a 32GB page file on a 93GB SSD, this equals the RAM. As a test we to reduce the page file and see if there was any bad side effects.

We decided on a page file with the Initial size of 25GB with Maximum size at 28GB. It rebooted overnight and when we come in this morning it looks like the page file is only 2527MB.

The server has been running fine so far, only 50% of the RAM is being used. If the test continues to be successful we want to roll it out but we are worried why the settings have been ignored. Anyone have any ideas why this has happened?

---

Wanted to post a picture however cant. At the top it shows C: with paging file size 25000 - 28000 (MB)

Then Custom size radio button with the dot in with initial size 25000 and maximum size 28000

At the bottom it displays 2567MB allocated.

Comment: Have you noticed the allocated size increasing since then?

Comment: It has now, it's 13.6GB. It looks like it grew overnight, it took 40+ hours of normal workload to change, I'm thinking an app may be leaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page file just wasn't using the space. It took 40+ hours of normal workload before I saw a change. I have a feeling one of our apps has a memory leak, this would explain the jump.